# IF Statement && Swift for Passing Data in Tableview

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

i want to pass multi data in tableview. if 1 data its work, but i will try to multi data.

how?

this my syntax but its not work

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    if let namaToko = namaToko && let lokasi = lokasi && let notelp = notelp {

        lblNamaToko.text = namaToko
        lblNoTelp.text = notelp
        lblLokasi.text = lokasi


    }

}
```

please help how must i do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unwrap your data first then assign to your variables or outlets.

```
if let namaToko = namaToko, let lokasi = lokasi, let notelp = notelp {    
  lblNamaToko.text = namaToko
  lblNoTelp.text = notelp
  lblLokasi.text = lokasi
}
```